# Why calculus method fails here for finding common tangent?

Tags: calculus, geometry, analytic-geometry

Q. Find equation of common tangent(s) to the parabola $y^2 = 16\sqrt{3}x$ and the ellipse $2x^2 + y^2 = 4$ . When I solve this question by using methods of conic section like using equation of tangent at parabola $y = mx + \frac{a}{m}$  and for ellipse $y = mx \pm \sqrt{m^2 a^2 + b^2}$. and then comparing the constant term i get $m=2,-2$.
But when I solve this question by calculus method by equating $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at point $(h,k)$ for both curves .I didnt get the right ans.
This questions was asked by IIT JEE in 2012. Please Help...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please format your question using MathJax, and please add the steps in both your attempts (including the one that didn't give the right answer), so that users can help you better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A common tangent has a tangent point in the second quadrant for the ellipse and the first quadrant for the parabola. 
Assuming your slope of $2$ is correct, I get the point on the ellipse as $(\frac{-2\sqrt3}{3},\frac{2\sqrt3}{3})$ where $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-2x}{\sqrt{4-2x^2}}$ and then the equation of the tangent $y = 2x + 2\sqrt3$. This works and is tangent to the parabola at $(\sqrt 3, 4\sqrt 3)$ where 
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2(3)^{1/4}}{\sqrt x} = 2$ at $x = \sqrt 3$.

Your mistake "may" have been in setting the derivatives equal to each other which gives a single x value which is not at either tangent point.

[image]

Comment: Following the procedure of calculus (i.e. by using application of derivatives and without using conic section). I cannot get the slope of the common tangent.

Comment: I have got the slope of the common tangent = 2 by using conic section and not by calculus..How can i get it by using dy/dx at the point of contact of two curves.

Comment: In fact when we sketch the two curves they cut each other but not touch..? Then how's common tangent possible.

Comment: See added sketch to my answer.

Comment: Ohhh I see it now . I am sorry . I was  misunderstanding the ques.. Thanx sir